# how do i connect my app.config connection string to my code

Tags: c#, database, connection, oledb

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            DataTable dt = con.GetSchema("TABLES").AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("TABLE_TYPE") == "TABLE").CopyToDataTable();
            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
                comboBoxTabel.Items.Add(r["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error met databank connectie." + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

What I want is that I'm able to make a connection string inside my code WITHOUT a path that connects to the connection string inside of the app.config(here is the path).

Comment: if i use:                                                  var con = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString; then i get an error with the GetSchema because it sais it can't connect with a string

Comment: what exception do you get? Put it in your question, it will be helpful to people trying to answer

Comment: https://gyazo.com/a71ab2d4a6018a828773b5103f5cb92e I know how to add a connecting string but idk how to add one without getting this error so my question hasn't been aswered :/ @Crowcoder

Comment: The issue isn't the connection string, it's that you're using the wrong object, use `connection` rather than `con`, also this isn't the code in your question, in the future it would be better to put the code that you are actually having issues with in the question, your code doesn't even instantiate or declare your variable `con`

Comment: ty vm! sry am in hurry :/

Answer (score 0):

**Use the configuration manager**

You should use the [ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) to do this

```
var cstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString
using(var connection = new OleDbConnection(cstr))
{
   //do stuff with connection
}
```

**Your error has nothing to do with the connection string**

Please read the error carefully, you are trying to preform operation on a string, your variable `con`, you should be doing the operations on the object `connection` based off of the image you provided

Comment: @Viktor, that is not a connection string error. You have resolved that problem and you have a new one.

Comment: @Viktor, you are trying to preform db operations on your string, not the connection object, also you should put the image in your question not in the comments of an answer